# Why is Android Studio showing an error when I try to use setText() on a Button?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app where I'm trying to run a timer for as long as the phone is asleep/idle. The timer will stop as soon as the phone is turned on.

Here's the (relevant) code in main.java:

```
public void changeAppState(View view) {
        view = (Button) changeAppStateButton;
        Log.i("BUTTON", "Tapped!");
        if (isAppRunning) { //If the app is running, stop app
            isAppRunning = false;
            view.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPurple));
            view.setText("Start Reminder"); //There's an error here
            timer.cancel();
            Log.i("TIMER", "Timer interrupted");

        } else { //If the app is not running, start app
            //some code

            isAppRunning = true;
            view.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorRed));
            view.setText("Stop Reminder"); //There's an error here

            //some more code
        }
    }
```

This is the XML for the button:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changeAppStateButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
        android:background="#9C27B0"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alegreya_sans_sc"
        android:onClick="changeAppState"
        android:text="Start Reminder"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Android Studio highlights both occurrences of setText() in the function. I don't see any error message.
Can someone tell me why setText() isn't working in the function? Let me know if you need more of the code.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: What is the changeAppStateButton reference?

Comment: There is no error message other than "Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String)'

Comment: @Jaeheon Shim - I'm sorry, what reference?

Comment: Ah, OK, the extra code reveals the issue. `view = (Button) changeAppStateButton;` – That doesn't change the type that `view` was declared as, which is `View`, which does not have a `setText()` method. You want to do something like `Button button = (Button) view;`, and use `button` in place of `view` in the following lines.

Comment: @MikeM. It worked. Thank you!

Comment: @MikeM. you might want to submit that as an answer

Comment: This should also work: `Button btn = findViewById(R.id.changeAppStateButton);` and then `btn.setText("Start Remainder");` right ? @MikeM

Comment: @samdy1 It's all yours, if you'd like to post one. Please feel free to do so. Cheers!

Comment: @Ahtisham Yep, that'd work too. In this particular case, though, it seemed that the OP was unfamiliar with the use and effects of casting, so I geared my suggestion toward that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reassigning of `view` doesn't change the type of the variable from `View` to `Button` as it gets re-cast automatically back to `View`.

Instead, you need to initialise a variable of type `Button` like so:

```
Button button = (Button) changeAppStateButton;
```

(or, as [@Ahtisham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5067761/ahtisham) pointed out, if you haven't already got a reference to the change app state button)

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.changeAppStateButton);
```

Since this new variable is of type `Button`, you will be able to access its `setText` method.